# Facing four mate threats

Tags: no-computers, chess

Just a regular chess puzzle. White to move and win.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A simple win would be

> 1. Bxh7+ Kh8 
>  2. Bxe4+ Kg8 
>  3. Bh7+  Kh8 
>  4. Bxd3+ Kg8 
>  5. Bh7+  Kh8 
>  6. Ng6+  fxg6 
>  7. Bxg6+ Kg8 
>  8. Bh7+  Kh8 
>  9. Bb1+  Kg8 
>  10. Bxa2+ Re6 
>  11. Bxe6++

But I don't know if this is minimal

Comment: Nice work! This is the intended answer. I created this back in 2013 and nobody's solved it since. I figured it would be good for at least 30 minutes on this site ;)